# Returning value after recursively iterating through XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm working with a very nested XML file and the path is critical for understanding. This answer enables me to print both the path and value: [Python xml absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475377/python-xml-absolute-path)

What I can't figure out is how to output the result in a more usable way (trying to construct a dataframe listing Path and Value).

For example, from the linked example:

```
<A>
  <B>foo</B>
  <C>
    <D>On</D>
  </C>
  <E>Auto</E>
  <F>
    <G>
      <H>shoo</H>
      <I>Off</I>
    </G>
  </F>
</A>
```

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML(your_xml_string)

def print_path_of_elems(elem, elem_path=""):
    for child in elem:
        if not child.getchildren() and child.text:
            # leaf node with text => print
            print "%s/%s, %s" % (elem_path, child.tag, child.text)
        else:
            # node with child elements => recurse
            print_path_of_elems(child, "%s/%s" % (elem_path, child.tag))

print_path_of_elems(root, root.tag)
```

Results in the following printout:

```
/A/B, foo
/A/C/D, On
/A/E, Auto
/A/F/G/H, shoo
/A/F/G/I, Off
```

I believe yield is the correct technique but I'm getting no where, current attempt returns nothing:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML(your_xml_string)

def yield_path_of_elems(elem, elem_path=""):
    for child in elem:
        if not child.getchildren() and child.text:
            ylddict = {'Path':elem_path, 'Value':child.text}
            yield(ylddict)
        else:
            # node with child elements => recurse
            yield_path_of_elems(child, "%s/%s" % (elem_path, child.tag))

for i in yield_path_of_elems(root):
    #print for simplicity in example, otherwise turn into DF and concat
    print(i)
```

From experimenting I believe when I use yield or return the recursion doesn't function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the values yielded by the recursive call back to the original caller. So change:

```
yield_path_of_elems(child, "%s/%s" % (elem_path, child.tag))
```

to

```
yield from yield_path_of_elems(child, "%s/%s" % (elem_path, child.tag))
```

This is analogous to the way you have to use `return recursive_call(...)` in a normal recursive function.

Comment: Thank you! This is my first time using yield and obviously didn't fully understand how to utilize it.